# How to orderby (sort) by date ignoring time?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I have a DateTime field in a MongoDB collection. I can't find a way to orderby just the date portion of the DateTime field. SortOrderDate is a DateTime field but I want to sort just the Date portion of the DateTime field. I'm using C# and it's native MongoDB driver.

```
   var collection = MongoDatabase.GetCollection<ISummary>("summary");
        var items = (from e in collection.AsQueryable()
            where e.SortOrderDate >= today.Date
                  && e.SortOrderDate < today.AddDays(1).Date
            orderby e.SortOrderDate descending, e.SortOrder ascending, e.Views descending 
            select e).Skip(0).Take(count).ToList();
```

Comment: Why? If you have multiple items in the same date how would you want them to be sorted?

Comment: It's the same date but different time. If it's the same date I want to use the sortorder to sort. I guess I could just remove sortorderdate from the orderby because the filter gives me the items for one day.

Comment: NoSQL in general is all about storing the data the way you want to query it. Though it's not about keeping data normalized, you should denormalize it when you need to. So I'd suggest to simply store your timestamp twice: 1. as datetime and 2. as date with time set to 00:00:00.